# When trying to add a value it just gives the new value C#

Tags: c#

I am making a banking ap that keeps track off the amount of money someone has in the bank (called Saldo)
So i created a constuctor that assigns a name to a account and this keeps track of everys person balance
however in my current code i can only add money once and when i change the input it automatically  changes to that and doesnt add or subtract (what it is suposed to do)

the important parts of the code are

```
    private void StortL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bankrekening BankrekeningL = new Bankrekening(bankrekeningLinks.Naam, 0);

        double saldodouble = 0;
        int bedrag = 0;
        int decimalL = 0;
        int wholeL = 0;
        decimalL = Convert.ToInt32(tbDecimaleL.Text);
        wholeL = Convert.ToInt32(tbWholeL.Text) * 100;
        bedrag = wholeL + decimalL;
        Bankrekening BankrekeningL2 = new Bankrekening(bankrekeningLinks.Naam, BankrekeningL.Saldo);
        BankrekeningL2.Stort(bedrag);
        lbIsaldoL.Text = Convert.ToString(BankrekeningL2.Saldo);
    }
}
}
```

And

```
class Bankrekening
{
    //datavelden
    private int rekeningnummer;
    private string naam;
    private int saldo;
    private static int volgendeVrijeRekeningnummer = 2001;
    //properties
    public int Rekeningnummer { get { return rekeningnummer; } }
    public string Naam { get { return naam; } }
    public int Saldo { get { return saldo; } }

    //constructors
    public Bankrekening(string naam)
    {
        this.naam = naam;
        saldo = 0;
        //volgendeVrijeRekeningnummer is klassevariable,
        //je kunt this niet gebruiken
        rekeningnummer = volgendeVrijeRekeningnummer++;
    }

    public Bankrekening(string naam, int saldo)     
    {
        this.naam = naam;
        this.saldo = saldo;
    } 

    public void NeemOp(int bedrag)
    {   
       saldo = saldo+bedrag;
    }

    public void Stort(int bedrag)
    {
        saldo = saldo + bedrag;    
    }

    public void MaakOverNaar(Bankrekening andereRekening, int bedrag)
    {
        //zelf invullen
    } 
}
```

So what currently is happening is that instead of adding the number in a text box to the value of saldo (the previous inputs of the text box) it just sets the value of saldo to the value of whatever is in the text box.
E.G. i want to add 50 to my bankacount to which i previously added 100 euros so my label that keeps track of the balance should give 150 but instead it gives me 50.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You missed the important part of the question, what is happening, where it happens, what you expect to happen, and what you have tried so far

Comment: My apologies I just edited my question and made the problem that i have as clear as possible

Comment: You're adding 0 to a variable that's zero and the print the first 0 and sooo...it gets you 0 (saldo). Seems ok to me.

Answer (score 0):

you are everytime creating a new object, rather than using the same object for a same person .
So if you have already created an object for persons AAA
and he is adding money , you need to use the same object created rather than creating it again .

this line i think is the problem :

> Bankrekening BankrekeningL = new Bankrekening(bankrekeningLinks.Naam, 0);

Possible solution :

You might keep a list of your Bankrekening objects , and using LINQ check if for a person the object is already present .

If it is present then use the same object , else create a new object.

Something like

```
List<Bankrekening> list = new  List<Bankrekening>();
 if(list.Any(x=>x.Name == "XYZ")> 
 // your code to add
else
    Bankrekening BankrekeningL2 = new Bankrekening(bankrekeningLinks.Naam, BankrekeningL.Saldo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the declaration of `BankrekeningL` outside of the function into the form to preserve its value, currently you are creating a new instance every button click

```
Bankrekening BankrekeningL;
public FormName()
{
    BankrekeningL = new Bankrekening("name");
}

private void StortL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double saldodouble = 0;
    int decimalL = Convert.ToInt32(tbDecimaleL.Text);
    int wholeL = Convert.ToInt32(tbWholeL.Text) * 100;
    int bedrag = wholeL + decimalL;
    BankrekeningL.Stort(bedrag);
    lbIsaldoL.Text = BankrekeningL.Saldo.ToString();
}
```